# Why doesn't setuid work with mount?

Tags: linux, mount, setuid

There is a **setuid** bit on the file.

```
user@host:~$ ls -l /bin/mount
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 40152 May 26 19:31 /bin/mount
```

Why does operating system require root access to execute the 'mount'?

```
user@host:~$ /bin/mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
mount: only root can do that
user@host:~$ sudo /bin/mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
user@host:~$ lsblk  | grep sdb

sdb      8:16   0  102M  0 disk
└─sdb1   8:17   0  101M  0 part /mnt
```

My `/etc/fstab`

```
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=026bb2d9-1c0c-4163-85a1-f83b2221eb34 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1

# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=aec6b039-13b1-4568-abb1-2be1f3429325 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: can you please post content of your `/etc/fstab`

Comment: Yes, @Rahul.
I have added the information to the question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unix has the concept of *real* and *effective* UIDs (and GIDs for that matter).

When you run a setuid program then the *effective* ID of the process is set to the owner of the file.

So in the case of `mount` you have an *effective* ID of `root`.  But you still have a *real* ID of `user`.

Programs such as `passwd` or `su` or `mount` can check the real ID to see who is running it and act differently accordingly.  For `passwd` this allows the `root` user to change another's password; for `su` it allows switching users without knowing the password.

For `mount` it allows users to mount their own filesystems *if* they are defined in `/etc/fstab` *and* have the `user` attribute associated with them

eg in my Debian `fstab` I have:

```
/dev/sr0        /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto     0       0
```

This means a non-root user can run `mount /dev/sr0` or `mount /media/cdrom0` and it will attempt to mount the CD/DVD.

This is logic built into the `mount` program itself; it checks the real ID of the caller.

Comment: I forgot about real and effective UIDs.
Now everything is clear. Thank you!

Comment: If you read the source code of mount you will see the check if you're really root. See for more details https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/sys-utils/mount.c#L58-L75